# Validity of the two-body system approximation in astrophysics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics, approximations

I'm taking an intro course in astrophysics and studying Kepler's Laws of planetary motion - all of which are built over the assumption that we can approximate our system to one where there's only two bodies (point masses) interacting.

But to what extent is this correct? What is the validity of the approximation?

Answer (score 1):

1. why do you not ask your teacher? 2, you can calculate the influence of a third body but only numerically. for example the way the moon goes around the earth is badly described by th 2 body system earth moon, but it is still a good approximation. the "assumption" is based on the unfortunate fact, that no one can solve more than 2 body problem analytically, an for a beginners course, the numerical methods, by which one found Neptun and Pluto, since Saturn behaved not like predicted with the 2 body problem.